# hasMany auto relation in ext JS 6

Tags: extjs, has-many

I'm trying to implement a simple parent children relation in the same entity with Ext js 6, where I will receive all the information in the JSON. It is working fine for the parent but I'm not able to display the children in the grid. I guess it is something really simple and the error should be in the model:

```
Ext.define('hashmanytest.model.Person', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
alias: 'model.Person',


 hasMany: {
    model: 'hashmanytest.model.Person',
    name: 'childs',
    associationKey: 'childs'
 },



fields: [
    { name:'name' , type:'string' },
    { name:'email' , type:'string' },
    { name:'phone' , type:'string' },
    { name:'id' , type:'string' },
    { name: 'parent', reference: 'hashmanytest.model.Person'}
]
});
```

Or in the store:

```
Ext.define('hashmanytest.store.Personnel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

alias: 'store.personnel',

model: 'hashmanytest.model.Person',

data: { items: [
    { name: 'Jean Luc', email: "jeanluc.picard@enterprise.com", phone: "555-111-1111", id:1, parent: {}, childs: [
        { name: 'Worf',     email: "worf.moghsson@enterprise.com",  phone: "555-222-2222", id:2},
        { name: 'Deanna',   email: "deanna.troi@enterprise.com",    phone: "555-333-3333", id:3},
        { name: 'Data',     email: "mr.data@enterprise.com",        phone: "555-444-4444", id:4}
    ]},
    { name: 'Worf',     email: "worf.moghsson@enterprise.com",  phone: "555-222-2222", id:2, parent:{ name: 'Jean Luc', email: "jeanluc.picard@enterprise.com", phone: "555-111-1111", id:1}, childs: []},
    { name: 'Deanna',   email: "deanna.troi@enterprise.com",    phone: "555-333-3333", id:3, parent:{ name: 'Jean Luc', email: "jeanluc.picard@enterprise.com", phone: "555-111-1111", id:1}, childs: []},
    { name: 'Data',     email: "mr.data@enterprise.com",        phone: "555-444-4444", id:4, parent:{ name: 'Jean Luc', email: "jeanluc.picard@enterprise.com", phone: "555-111-1111", id:1}, childs: []}
]},

proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'items'
    }
}
});
```

Anyway I created a fiddle with the implementation:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11gr

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model is fine, `record.childs()` returns a `store`. Use [`getCount()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getCount) instead of `length`:

```
{
     text: 'Children',
     sortable: true,
     flex: 2,
     renderer: function (value, metaData, record) {
         return record.childs().getCount();    
     }
}
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11gs